# AngularJs: ng-if reacting too late

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Im using ui.router and including my navigation like this in my main html file:

```
<header ng-if-start="logedin()"></header>
<navigation ng-if-end="logedin()"></navigation>
```

the `logedin()` boolean will be set through the `angular.module().run()` in this function:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, to)
```

If i click logout in one of the navigation, the controller of the navigation will trigger this function:

```
$scope.logout = function() {
    store.remove('jwt');
    $state.go('login');
}
```

The Problems is after the `$state.go` the navigation is not hiding, but after refreshing the page.

Do i have to rerender the main index template/view (and then how)? Or how could I solve this problem?

Comment: `ng-if-end` not need for `logedin()`  change `ng-if-end="logedin"` for just `ng-if-end`

Comment: that fix your problem ?

Comment: unfortunately not :(

Comment: Can you put the logedin() method?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `ng-if-start="logedin"` with `ng-show="logedin"`? Also, are you sure that `logedin ` becomes false? Try printing it, or inspect the angular scope using an extension or dev tools. Where do you set `logedin` to false? ng-if removes the element from the dom, while *destroying its scope*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I solved it myself. Sorry for not providing the logedin() method.

The problem was:

```
$scope.logedin = function() {
return $rootScope.logedin
}
```

The `$rootScope.logedin` was set in the `angular.module().run()`-function.

To solve it i had to create a simple getter/setter service.

```
angular.module('sample')
    .service('sharedLogedIn', function () {
        var property = true;

        return {
            getProperty: function () {
                return property;
            },
            setProperty: function(value) {
                property = value;
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Good to know the issue was resolved. What might be happening is your values are not propagated... I might do this to troubleshoot:

```
<header ng-if="loggedinBool"></header>
<navigation ng-if="loggedinBool"></navigation>
```

1) Assign loggedin() value to a scope model or service property (preferably) loggedinBool and see if the values are propagated after logout which changes loggedinBool value.

2) If that does not work try $broadcast/$emit in loggout and capture that to change value of loggedinBool. This should automatically provide two-way-binding else try $scope.digest() or $scope.apply() method to see if values propagates.